# Is there a MapReduce library for Delphi?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, mapreduce

I recently read this great article which succinctly explains the power of Google's MapReduce:

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/08/01.html

In Mastering Delphi 2009, Marco Cantu shows a multi-threaded for loop using Anonymous functions, which is basically the Map part of MapReduce, but said it wasn't complete and there were other samples out there.  I'm also vaguely aware of someone at Embarcadero working on a DTL library but I haven't seen much on it lately.

So, are there solid implementations of MapReduce in Delphi available for use?

I'm aware of this handy library from Andreas Hausladen, if there's no general Map Reduce, is this the best library to build off of?

http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/?page_id=100

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Craig Stuntz wrote a series of posts on his blog (starting [here](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2008/09/09/37833/)) on higher order functions, and map and fold/reduce in particular. While not a "solid implementation of MapReduce in Delphi available for use", it's certainly a good place to start when implementing your own!

Comment: +1, but there is an even earlier blog posting that is very important in this regard: http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2008/01/24/37787/ Worth thinking about for those really interested in using FP concepts within Delphi programming.

Comment: Sorry, but both links are dead.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Hadoop Streaming to make Hadoop compatible with a mapper and reducer written in any language. Your input-file(s), mapper, and reducer will all interact using STDIN and STDOUT.